# How to run VBA event only once in a day?

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a script to a macro file and called that specific macro using a VBA project (personal.xlsb).
Every time any Excel is open (Workbook_open).

But now I only want to restrict that call to once a day.
For example if the individual macro calls that specific macro once a day, then the event is postponed to the next day and the macro is not called upon opening any Excel file.

Please tell me how I can ban my event performing only once a day, and the next event should take place the next day.

Thank you

```
Sub run()

Application.run "'C:\Users\850051636\OneDrive - Genpact\Desktop\Working\Project 5 WIP Stock Transfer\Working QPA_Stock Transfer_Draft_v1.0.xlsm'!Module1.test"

End Sub
```

Comment: Best way is to store the date in a hidden sheet when the macro is first run. Next time check for today's date when you open the file and if it is same as the date on the hidden sheet, then do not run the macro.

Comment: You can't "ban" the event from occurring but you can prevent action from being taken when the event occurs. For example, you might write the current date and time to a CustomDocumentProperty (or even a BuiltIn one) and check the current date/time against that note every time the event occurs, doing nothing if less than 24 hours have passed or if it's on the same day - whatever your rules are.

Comment: Hi @Variatus Can you please help me with CustomDocumentProperty how can i create this??

Comment: Use OS Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
    Sub test()
        If Sheet1.Range("F1").Value <> Date Then
            Sheet1.Range("F1").Value = Date 'save the date to your sheet
            '<put the rest of your code here>
            ActiveWorkbook.Save 'you can choose where you save
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: But the problem is I don't want to put this code on my main macro file I just want to add this event on personal.xlsb so that if any excel open in system the code run automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This function will add a CustomDocumentProperty of *Date* type by the name of `PropName` to `ThisWorkbook` if it didn't already exist. If a date is supplied for its value the supplied date will replace any previously existing. If the function is called without a value it returns whatever value exists for the specified property. In this mode, if the property doesn't exist a blank is returned.

```
Private Function SetGetProperty(ByVal PropName As String, _
                                Optional ByVal PropVal As Date) As Variant
    ' SSY 050 ++
    ' return the value of the property
    
    ' if PropVal is not omitted,
    ' assign PropVal to document Property(PropName)
    ' create a custom property of Date type if it didn't exist
    
    Dim Pp As DocumentProperty

    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook               ' change to suit
        Set Pp = .CustomDocumentProperties(PropName)
    
        If IsDate(PropVal) Then
            If Err.Number Then
                .CustomDocumentProperties.Add _
                               Name:=PropName, LinkToContent:=False, _
                               Type:=msoPropertyTypeDate, Value:=PropVal
            Else
                Pp.Value = PropVal
            End If
        End If
    End With
    SetGetProperty = Pp.Value
End Function
```

Please add the following code to your Workbook_Open procedure (for example).

```
If SetGetProperty("LastDone") < Date Then
    ' run your update here
    SetGetProperty "LastDone", Date
End If
```

In the first line the function asks the value of the property "LastDone". You can choose any valid name. The test will evaluate to *False* if the property doesn't exist. In that case, or if the date in the propterty is before today, your update will run and the property will set created/set with the current date.

Comment: I have try this code as well but still application run every time excel open.

Comment: With correct installation that isn't possible. Therefore the installation is wrong. Step through your code with F8. Let me know what you find. If you don't find the error, post your Workbook_Open procedure. You can add that to your original question in Edit mode.